# using title() creates a extra line in python

Tags: python-3.x

Purpose: Writing a code to capitalize the first letter of each word in a file.
Steps include opening the file in read mode and using title() in each line.
When the output is printed it creates extra blank line between each line in the file.

For example:

if the content is

```
one two three four                                                        
five six seven eight
```

output is:

```
One Two Three Four

Five Six Seven Eight
```

Not sure why the space shows up there

I used strip() followed by title() to escape the spaces but would like to know why we get spaces.

```py
inputfile = input("Enter the file name:")
openedfile = open(inputfile, 'r')
for line in openedfile:
    capitalized=line.title()
    print(capitalized)
```

the above code prints output with an added blank line

solved it using below code:

```py
inputfile = input("Enter the file name:")
openedfile = open(inputfile, 'r')
for line in openedfile:
    capitalized=line.title().strip()
    print(capitalized)

Expected to print capitalized words without spaces by just using title() and not title().strip()
```

Comment: It isn't `title()` which puts extra newline there. You are reading lines with `\n` at the end and the `print()` function adds another `\n` at the end.

Comment: does that mean we should always use a strip() at end of each title() to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I personally would get rid of newlines as soon as possible - so before the `title()`